# How to retrieve IP Address from a VM that can't have Guest Adiitions Installed

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, automation, guest-additions

I am trying to Automate the build and deploy process of a piece of server software we make, this software runs on ubuntu 12.04 but doesn't allow "apt-get" for security reasons.

I have gotten as far as installing the VM using VBoxManage however to run our automated test suit I need the IPV4 Address of said server.

Is there a way to get an IP without using Guest additions eg

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get <VMNAME> "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/V4/IP"
```

Thanks

EDIT: the use of `guestcontrol` was suggested as it doesn't need guest additions, however the `run` subcommand (or `execute` for pre VirtualBox 5) does require GA installed to function.  Using the `execute` sub command returns

`VBoxManage: error: The guest execution service is not ready (yet)`

Comment: how about VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate VM_NAME | grep "Net.*V4.*IP"?

Comment: I tried that earlier, returns nothing.  The full enumerate only shows 4 "HostInfo" lines

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to log into the guest, just run ifconfig.

If that isn't possible, try arp -a.

Comment: As this is part of an automation mannually logging in and entering a command wont work for me.  The goal is to get the IP address from a command line that can >> the result of said command to a text file to be read for the automated test suite

Comment: Can you give some more information on this automation process then?

Also, did you try running arp -a on the machine that hosts said VM?

Comment: using buildbot we create an ISO image of our product, then using a script and VBoxManage I create a custom VM and mount the ISO image which is then installed on the VM.  

Running arp -a returns the IP but with a "?" for a name rather than a server.domain.com, will that be consistant enough to safely use grep to search for "?" and the IP next to it?